# Google Apps Script not able to run function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script

The variable 'user' is not assigned the users email, and the label 'QT's text is not changed. Is this the correct way to call this function.

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    var user = google.script.run.getCurrentUser();
    $('#masterDiv').data('cUser', user);
    $('#QT').text(user);
});



//Server function
function getCurrentUser() {
    var userEmail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
    return userEmail;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost, you must include a `withSuccessHandler`, since `google.script.run` calls are asynchronous Javascript doens't wait for it to return something to continue the code, here:

```
$(document).ready( function (){
    var user = google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(whatToDo).getCurrentUser();
});

function whatToDo( returnedFromServer ){
    $('#masterDiv').data('cUser', returnedFromServer);
    $('#QT').text(user);
}
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. But now it is causing a NetworkError when I try to upload a file to my drive through apps script. I actually have another question currently open about it, Thanks for the help though.